# Sending MIDI data over HTTP

Tags: http, post, encoding, midi

How can I efficiently transfer MIDI data to remote client over HTTP (POST)?
There are no real time issues here, I just don't know how to encode the data.

Should I use plain string-pairs? I think a better way will be to just send the binary data
over the HTTP, I just don't know how to do it.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options:

1. Encode the MIDI in [base 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) and send it as the body of the POST (not sure what language you're using but most languages should have base 64 support readily available)
2. Go the `multipart/form-data` route and actually send the file

Comment: What's not clean about option #2?

Comment: Not saying it isn't clean, just less clean than #1 IMO.  A pure vanilla HTTP request feels (and looks) nicer than multipart requests. That's all.

Comment: There is nothing not pure/vanilla about `multipart/form-data`.  If anything, I'd say it is clear.  You don't have the overhead of base-64 in size, and you don't have to decode that later.  In my opinion, it would be far more efficient to leave the data as-is rather than encoding and then sending.

Comment: To each his own I guess.  That's the reason I mentioned both options.  Ultimately boils down to what solution best suits your particular needs and best fits into both your client and server.